# How to get month (in string) diff in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get month diff as integer based on month names in string (January, February, March, etc.) ?

For example, I have a variable `declare @month varchar(20) = 'May'`;
and Select `DATEDIFF(month,  month(getdate()), @month)` should be 7 (the 
difference between October and May).

Comment: difference b/w Oct and May should be 7 or 5??

Comment: Hi Dalian, do you require the difference between them or do you need the month in integer

Comment: Or as I understand your question, you require the difference between the two months with result as an in integer?

Comment: I meant 7 (backward). May 2019 - October 2018 = 7.

Comment: @Birel Yes. I need integer as result.

Comment: What result you want if values are `May 2020` and `October 2018` ?

Comment: do you have the year, or is it just general, e.g. the period October to May?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I need only months between successive years (e.g. 2018 and 2019).

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you would use `datediff()`:

```
select datediff(month, '2010-01-15', '2011-02-28')
```

This counts the number of month boundaries between two dates.  That sounds like a reasonable interpretation of your question.

Comment: Month names are in string.

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @M1 varchar(25) = 'October'
Declare @M2 varchar(25) = 'May'

Select DateDiff(MONTH,@M1+' 01 1980',@M2+' 01 1980')
       +case when DateDiff(MONTH,@M1+' 01 1980',@M2+' 01 1980')<0 then 12 else 0 end
```

**Returns 7**

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @M1 as varchar(20) = 'October';
DECLARE @M2 as varchar(20) = 'May';

SELECT ABS(datediff(mm,
                    convert(datetime, @M1 + ' 1 2012 11:01AM', 100),
                    convert(datetime, @M2 + ' 1 2012 11:01AM', 100) 
                    )
        );
```

this doesn't allow for years ,which you didn't mention previously

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input1,input2, there you go:

```
declare @input1 nvarchar(max)='October'
declare @input2 nvarchar(max)='May'

select 
    case 
        when DATEPART(MM,@input1+' 01 2011')>DATEPART(MM,@input2+' 01 2011') 
            then 12 
        else 0
    end-DATEPART(MM,@input1+' 01 2011')+DATEPART(MM,@input2+' 01 2011')
```

Comment: @Dalian, I think George gave you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: This is strange, the site's parser ignores END?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select  DATEPART(MM,'march 01 2011') - DATEPART(MM,'january 01 2011')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but something like this might work:

```
select MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('October', '%M')) - MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('May', '%M')) -- returns 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Date1 VARCHAR(10),@Date2  VARCHAR(10)
SET @Date1='January'
SET @Date2='DECEMBER'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Number AS EnglishMOnthNumber,
        DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,NUMBER-DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()),GETDATE())) AS EnglishMOnth
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE NUmber Between 1 and 12
AND type='P'
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN EnglishMOnth=@Date2 THEN EnglishMOnthNumber END) 
      - MAX( CASE WHEN EnglishMOnth=@Date1 THEN EnglishMOnthNumber END ) AS DiffInMonths
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the difference between the required month (in your case May) and current month, If the difference is less than 0 then I would add the number of months (12) to it to get the calculation else nothing would be added. This is just one more way better answers above

```
declare @RequiredMonth varchar(25) = 'February';
declare @difference as int;

set @difference = MONTH(cast(@RequiredMonth+'1 2016' as datetime)) - MONTH(getdate())

select case when  @difference >= 0 then  @difference else @difference + 12 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
DECLARE
    @month varchar(20) = 'May'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), EndDate)
FROM (SELECT CAST(@month  + CAST( YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4))  AS DATE) EndDate) D
```